# Using SciTE to compile/build/run a C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to use SciTE to compile/build/run a C program that I have contructed. However, everytime I tell it to go, I get the error, "The system cannot find the file specified.". I don't know how to fix it or what could be the problem? Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 4):

The [SciTE FAQ](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEFAQ.html) may help you:

```
#CannotFindFile When I try to compile/build/run my [some language] source files,
I get the following error: 'The system cannot find the file specified'.

Make sure that the path to your compiler is set correctly on your system. Try to
execute from console the same command you get in SciTE and see if it works. You
can also search in your [language].properties for the compile commands used. If
you have a different compiler or use different arguments, edit the commands to suit
your needs. The lines to look for:
command.compile.filepattern=
command.build.filepattern=
command.go.filepattern=
```